# Pointers + structs + functions in C identifier undefined

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

So this is my code and I don't understand why I get that identifier "pers" is undefined, when I'm clearly pointing at it from another function, which is as far as I know, the utility of pointers.

I've gone through some research but nothing seemed to solve my issue since I'm dealing with structs and all that.

*Also one of the requirements is that tle so called "leer_persona();" cant have any value in the parenthesis*

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int num;
    char letra;
}tdni;
typedef struct{
    char nom[20];
    tdni dni;
}tpersona;

tpersona leer_persona();
void mostrar_persona(tpersona p);

int main(){
    tpersona pers;
    pers = leer_persona();
    mostrar_persona(pers);

    return 0;
}

tpersona leer_persona(){
    int i=0;
    int *fp;
    fp = &pers;
```

Thanks.

Comment: The scope of the `pers` variable is only inside the `main` function because  variables defined inside functoins have their scope limited to inside the function. If you want to refer to that struct instance from a different function, either make `pers` a global variable or pass a pointer to `pers` as a *function parameter* to `leer_persona`. Of course you're going to have to modify the function signature of `leer_persona` to accept a point to a `tpersona` struct like so: `tpersona leer_persona(tpersona* pers) {...`

Comment: @OmerTuchfeld so no pointers at all then?

Comment: Even if you have access to the `pers` variable inside the `leer_persona` function, your conversion from `tpersona *` (the type of `&pers`) to `int *` (the type of `fp`) is invalid. What are you really trying to do? What is the actual problem you try to solve with your program?

Comment: You can either define `leer_persona` to receive a `tpersona` struct by value and also return a `tpersona` struct by value, in which case a copy will be performed in each direction and no pointers will be needed, or you can define `leer_persona` to receive a pointer to a `tpersona` struct (`tpersona*`), in which case, only the pointer itself will be copied instead of the entire struct, and `leer_persona` will modify the struct via the pointer.

Comment: @OmerTuchfeld WORKED!!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pers has function scope in "main()".  It is not visible outside of "main()".

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/
>
> Function scope begins at the opening of the function and ends with the
> closing of it.

See this link for more details: [C - Scope Rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope)

If you want to use "pers" in another function, you'd typically pass it as a function parameter, e.g. `tpersona leer_persona(tpersona * pers)`.  In this example, I passed parameter "pers" [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm), instead of copying [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value).